react context typescript error The expected type comes from property 'auth' which is declared here on type 'IAuthContext
I want to create a context with typescript but I got following error:
on AuthContext.provider at value auth:
Type 'IAuthContext' is missing the following properties from type '{ session: TAuthSession | null; user: TAuthUser | null; }': session, userts(2739)
authContext.tsx(5, 3): The expected type comes from property 'auth' which is declared here on type 'IAuthContext'

and on authContext.provider at value setAuth
Type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<IAuthContext>>' is not assignable to type '(data: IUserAuth) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'value' and 'data' are incompatible.
    Type 'IUserAuth' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<IAuthContext>'.ts(2322)
authContext.tsx(9, 3): The expected type comes from property 'setAuth' which is declared here on type 'IAuthContext'

Here is my code:
code:
import React, { createContext, useState } from "react";
import { IUser, IUserAppMetaData, IUserAuth } from "../api/login/types";

export type TAuthSession = {
  access_token: string;
  expires_in: number;
  expires_at: number;
  refresh_token: string;
}

export type TAuthUser = {
  id: string;
  email: string;
  app_metadata: IUser,
  user_metadata: IUserAppMetaData,
};

export interface IAuthContext {
  auth: {
    session: TAuthSession | null;
    user: TAuthUser | null;
  };
  setAuth: (data: IUserAuth) => void;
}

const AuthContext = createContext<IAuthContext>({auth: {
  session: null,
  user: null
}, setAuth: () => {}});

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }: { children?: React.ReactNode; }) => {
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState<IAuthContext>({auth: {
    session: null,
    user: null
  }, setAuth: () => {}});

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{auth, setAuth}}>
        {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default AuthContext;

I dont know how to fix it because all types are correct except at authContext.provider I dont know how to solve it what I am doing wrong here ?
